# Android SDK: Update platform tools

Tags: android, eclipse

I currently have Android SDK Platform-tools 14 installed. *(Edit: Seems to be the current version)*

Since this has a bug that makes Logcat unusable and it seems to be [fixed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7829487/how-can-i-stop-the-logcat-output-from-scrolling-automatically-in-eclipse) in newer versions, Id like to update it.

How can this be done?

SDK Mangager.exe does not find a newer version than 14. I restarted it multiple times and installed all available updates.
The [android page](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/tools-notes.html) says the current version is 20 but they don't provide a download.
Installing the latest SDK starter package doesn't solve it.

Screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Google page is talking about the tools not for platform tools.Actually there are two different folders in SDK one is tools and one is platform-tools so as per the latest release there latest version is

for platform-tools :[platform Tools](http://dl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools_r14-windows.zip)

for tools :[Tools](http://dl.google.com/android/repository/tools_r20-windows.zip)

so if you are having problem just download the zip and replace the old one with new one installed.

if you are getting problem with the new catlog use the old one (LogCat-Deprecated).

Comment: Okay, seems like I confused tools with platform-tools and I'm up to date? Since the current platform-tools is r14? Then I wonder why I encounter the scroll error that should be fixed since SDK Tools r15?

Comment: @Toast: "Okay, seems like I confused tools with platform-tools and I'm up to date?" -- yes, you are up to date. "Then I wonder why I encounter the scroll error that should be fixed since SDK Tools r15?" -- I do not know what scroll error you are referring to. Consider opening up an issue on http://b.android.com.

Comment: [This scroll problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7829487/how-can-i-stop-the-logcat-output-from-scrolling-automatically-in-eclipse)

Answer (score 0):

Launch standalone SDK manager and not from Eclipse. It then should fetch list of available packages and offer you to update all old packages, as your ADT v14 is quite ancient.

Alternatively, if everything else fail, you always can fetch ADT by hand from http://tools.android.com, unpack tools to your , replacing old stuff and then installing Eclipse plugin. Please note you need to download both and install as latest version will not work with outdated packages.

Comment: I got the described problem when using the standalone SDK manager. On tools.android.com I didnt find the download of the tools. I only found a link to the SDK download (what I already tried to install)

Comment: There's "Download" link on left side, which leads to http://tools.android.com/download Go there or directly to latest tools http://tools.android.com/download/adt-21-preview  scroll down for installation instructions. Or if that's not working, download previous version from: http://tools.android.com/download/adt-20-preview - download `tools` archive, unpack and replace your `<SDK>/tools` with its content, and then download `adt20-preview3.zip` and install from Eclipse -> Help -> Install New Software -> Add... -> Archve... and point to downloaded zip file. Or remove your SDK and do fresh install

Comment: I just realised you are talking about `platfrom-tools` not `tools`. My advices are about `tools`. Platform tools are recently at v14 so you are up to date. Sorry